# How to limit JS animation to the input field you clicked into, not all of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Messing with the jawbreaker-esque input animation found in this [code pen](https://codepen.io/wedranb/pen/Lsfry)

The code pen only has ONE field, but if you add a second, like this...

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="lb">username</p>
  <p class="placeholder">username</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <p class="lb">username2</p>
  <p class="placeholder">username2</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

And then add this CSS so the 2nd field moves down below the 1st...

```
.container2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You'll see that when you click into either input field, the desired animation happens to both.

So how could I change the JS so that it only happens to the input field you click into?

Comment: Can you please just post the problematic pen, or better yet, [edit] your question to put it in a stack snippet right here?

Comment: Use the keyword `this` to reference the clicked element in your JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$.parent()` to get the parent, then target `.placeholder`, `.border` and `.lb` relative to the parent of the `input` that was clicked.

```js
 $('input[type=text]').blur(function(){
   $parent = $(this).parent();
   $parent.find('.placeholder').removeClass("placeholder--animate");
   $parent.find('.border').removeClass("border--animate");
   $parent.find('.lb').removeClass("lb--animate");
   checkInput($(this));
 })
 .focus(function() {  
   $parent = $(this).parent();
   $parent.find('.placeholder').addClass("placeholder--animate");
   $parent.find('.border').addClass("border--animate");
   $parent.find('.lb').addClass("lb--animate");
   checkInput($(this));
 });

 function checkInput($input) {
   if ( $input.val()) {
       $input.prev('.placeholder').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      $input.prev('.placeholder').css('display', 'visible');
    }
 }
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600,400,300);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type=text] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #7f8c8d;
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #95a5a6;
  transition: .2s all ease-out;
}

.lb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -30px;
  z-index: 40;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #3498db;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s all ease-out;
}

.lb--animate {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}

.placeholder--animate {
  left: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #3498db;
  transition: .2s width ease-out;
}

.border--animate {
  width: 100%;
}

.container2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p class="lb">username</p>
  <p class="placeholder">username</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <p class="lb">username2</p>
  <p class="placeholder">username2</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this quick/perfect answer!  Curious, can you make it so after you fill out the field and tab to the next one, the blue small label STAYS above the filled out field, rather than disappear?  I guess a 3rd state would need to be implemented, right? (since it's only default and animated currently)

Comment: @user3304303 you're welcome :) try commenting out all of the code inside of the blur function - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yep!  Can't believe it was that easy. I really gotta step up my JS game ASAP.  Thank you again for the knowledge!

Comment: @user3304303 awesome, you're welcome. btw, if you want to do that, just remove the whole `.blur(...)` line, and just use `$('input[type=text]').focus()`